# E: Package 'pkg-config' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, package-management, 14.10, mongodb, pkg-config

I am on Ubuntu 14.10 and I try to install new mongodb driver, but I have this error:

```
configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's libraries
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/configure' failed
```

I find that i need before installing new driver to install pkg-config, but when I try that I get following error:

```
E: Package 'pkg-config' has no installation candidate
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: how you install ?? try to follow these guides
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/

Comment: I'm not trying to install mongo, but mongodb driver for php.

Comment: oops ! sorry check this question may helping you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459164/easiest-way-to-install-mongodb-php-extension-in-ubuntu-13-10-saucy

Comment: can you post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list `

Comment: You are getting this error because 14.10 went End-Of-Life a while ago and its repositories have since been archived. Upgrade to a supported release to continue receiving updates and support (currently: 12.04, 14.04, 15.10 (will go EOL next month), and 16.04). Voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: @R00t  http://pastebin.com/vpeC5bQR

Comment: @OstMil like Paranoid Panda said you are using a version of ubuntu that is no longer supported. I can only think of 3 options, you upgrade, you [change the links](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release?lq=1) in the source.list from archive.ubuntu.com to old-releases.ubuntu.com or you compile everything from source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Ubuntu 14.10 : Please replace all text in `/etc/apt/sources.list` with this new text

```
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-backports multiverse universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security multiverse universe
```

... and run `sudo apt-get update`

Installing "OpenSSL's libraries" : `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev pkg-config`

---